# How does GRUB 2 work under multiple Linux partitions with UEFI

Tags: linux, grub2, uefi, boot-loader

When we install a new Linux, the installer will install a bootloader (efi file) at EFI partition and update the menu entry at NVRAM, and most likely set the newly added bootloader as default. The bootloader will read the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to load the kernel and initrd.

My question is, when there are multiple bootloaders (.efi) reside in ESP, are they identical? Since they are all GRUB2. Can each of them discover all the kernels in the system?

Since each OS's partition has `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, which one is being read by the default bootloader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, when there are multiple bootloaders (.efi) reside in ESP, are they identical? since they are all grub2. Can all of them discover all the kernel in the system?

If there are multiple UEFI Linux installations on a disk, they normally use the same EFI System Partition (ESP), but their respective EFI executables live in different subdirectories of the ESP, of the form `EFI/bootloader-id`. The EFI executables have the same name; for 64 bit installations it is `grubx64.efi`. So the EFI variables would be located at `EFI/bootloader-id/grubx64.efi`

These executables are installed by `grub-install` running on their respective systems, though you might have to point `grub-install` to that partition using `--efi-directory`. And you may also have to choose the 
value of `bootloader-id` with `--bootloader-id`. Different Linux distributions have different defaults for `bootloader-id`. For example, Debian defaults to `debian`. For more information about `grub-install` options, see `man grub-install`.

`grub-install` hard-wires the name of the boot/root devices into those executables using UUIDs.

These EFI executables are executed by the EFI firmware on the motherboard. Since the EFI executable knows the boot/root devices for its Linux installation, and since, by definition, `grub.cfg` has a fixed location relative to the  boot/root devices, the EFI executable can execute the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` corresponding to that installation.  And `grub.cfg` of course has all the information needed to do a boot, including the names of the kernels installed on the system.

[The Arch Wiki GRUB page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems) has good coverage of these matters.
See also [the Debian Wiki UEFI page](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI).

Comment: very good explanation. From what I understand, the **EFI/bootloader-id/grubx64.efi** points to a kernel partition and execute **grub.cfg** when boot. For each **EFI/bootloader-id/grubx64.efi**, they also can boot other kernel. For example, **EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi** can display the menu including ubuntu and Fedora.  **EFI/fedora/grubx64.efi** can also boot ubuntu and Fedora, since they all using **grub2**, and  **grub.cfg** has the knowledge where are other kernel located.

Comment: @user3346398 Yes, the `grub.cfg` menu may display boot entries about other distributions (that it knows about) that are installed on the machines. I'm not sure how GRUB collects this information, and of course, `update-grub` corresponding to that `grub.cfg` would need to be run *after* the distribution in question was installed, otherwise no new entry would appear. There's also no guarantee that those other entries would be correct - GRUB maybe be operating with imperfect/incomplete information.